# Perl send email to web server without modules

Tags: perl, email, webserver

I writing a program to do some monitoring on a server (email:cms1@melitaplc.com) then send an email to my laptop (daniel.saliba@melitaplc.com) which is connected to a web server (smtp.melita.com). After my email daniel....I tried adding the smtp port i.e. sendEmail("daniel.saliba\@melitaplc.com:25",.....) but I got /export/home/cassi/dead.letter...

P.S I cannot install any CPAN modules hence the code below.

The program executes without any errors but I do not receive the email.

```
sendEmail("daniel.saliba\@melitaplc.com", "cms1\@melitaplc.com", "ALERT", "This is a  test" );

sub sendEmail
 {
    my ($to, $from, $subject, $message) = @_;
    my $sendmail = '/usr/lib/sendmail';
    open(MAIL, "|$sendmail -oi -t");
            print MAIL "From: $from\n";
            print MAIL "To: $to\n";
            print MAIL "Subject: $subject\n\n";
            print MAIL "$message\n";
    close(MAIL);
 }
```

Comment: "I cannot install any CPAN modules hence the code below." — You are [probably wrong about that](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=693828).

Comment: This is an old solaris 9 machine which is a company server so preferably I can find a solution without installing anything plus I tried and it didn't let me.

Comment: @dsaliba Did you actually read the link?

Comment: Did u try with `Net::SMTP` ? Its a core module.

Comment: Solaris 9 — this sounds like installing any decent CPAN module or recompiling perl would take eons...

Comment: Infact I got "Can't locate Net/SMTP.pm in @INC (@INC contains:..."

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have access to install CPAN modules then you probably can't read your mail logs either... so you could try running

```
/usr/lib/sendmail -oi -t -v
```

on the command line, feeding it the same text your script sends it, and seeing what it does.  The `-v` switch should give you lots of debugging information.